# How to hide report name in print menu based on the condition

Tags: odoo-16

`

```
<record id="action_report_inbound_slip" model="ir.actions.report">
<field name="name">Packing List</field>
<field name="model">stock.picking</field>
<field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
<field name="report_name">classic_system.report_total_packing</field>
<field name="report_file">classic_system.packing_list</field>
<field name="binding_model_id" ref="stock.model_stock_picking"/>
<field name="binding_type">report</field>
</record>`
```

this is the code for Packing List report
the Packing List in print menu should be viewed only when picking_type_code == 'incoming' else Packing List action should be hidden
That is descriptive name given to this action should be hidden based on different condition for same model